# Encouraging Kindness in Rich People?

Tags: humans, culture, psychology, humanoid, economy

As the video linked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L90R6PtxFKE) shows, there is some evidence linking greater wealth to a greater chance of being more of a jerk. Assuming that we're talking about humans or a sapient race with more or less human psychology, at least in this area, how might this tendency be fought against? The best idea I have so far is having rich kids perform certain chores to get them to appreciate their wealth.

Comment: A YouTube video by the famous sociologist AsapSCIENCE is *"significant evidence"*? Is "jerk" a standard sociological or psychological term in your country? *Why* do you want to prevent people from becoming rich -- do you believe that there can be a rich country inhabited only by poor people? Young people are *not* "jerks" and arguably cannot possibly be "rich" -- they are minors and cannot own wealth.

Comment: Eliminate money. No one will be rich. People will still be jerks though.

Comment: Questions seems off-topic to me.  More appropriate perhaps to either [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) or [Psychology & Neuroscience SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I put it here because I was trying to focus on what the culture could do, though I probably will ask in the psychology SE now that you mention it.

Comment: This is pretty much a real world problem that rich people are actually struggling to solve themselves - "How not to spoil your kids".

Comment: Having a lot of money doesn't make someone be either a good person or a bad person.  It just allows them to be more of what they already are.

Comment: Having to watch a video to answer a question is not a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

So first off to say that you don't have to be rich to be a jerk. I know plenty of people who aren't rich, and who are assholes.
Second, saying that rich people are jerks is stereotyping to the same extent as to say that women are bad drivers or that poor people are lazy.
I also know several rich people that do a lot of good for the local community and are definitely not jerks.

But for the sake of argument let's suppose this is an alternate world where what you say is mostly true. I'm also going to interpret "Jerk" as someone that puts themselves and what they desire over the needs of others or society, and a society that puts emphasis on making sure that people in general are better human beings.

So I propose a society where there is a law requiring all young people to serve in some kind of peace corps, similar to how some countries have laws forcing all citizens to serve in military service.

Rich and poor, they all have to take some time working "in the trenches", helping those in need and giving to society. During their time they don't have access to their families wealth so everyone is equal, working side by side.

This will help teach "the rich" that poor people are people too.
And it will help teach "the poor" that rich people are people too.

And it'll teach everyone about empathy and the value of hard work.

Comment: Forcing me to do something will not have a good effect.  If I was drafted into an army I would totally lose all patriotism for that country.  If I was drafted into a organization that helped a certain type of people I would desire to do what I could to harm those people once I got out of the organization.  No matter how worthy I may think a cause is, once I am forced to serve that cause I will always be opposed to it.   And I believe that a significant proportion of people are as contrary as I am.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Could be, though there are things that society could do to minimize those kinds of responses. I mean, there were a lot of young men that volunteered to go over to WW1, knowing the hell hole that it was, simply because the ones that didn't were ridiculed, shamed, and demonized by everyone. And it was not good. There are probably less wrong ways to do the same thing. For instance men in the US have to sign up for selective service at 18, which lets you renew your drivers license, apply for loans and grants, and not go to prison for failure to register.

Comment: In this society it could be a matter of citizenship. "Service is completely optional! Except that if you don't serve then you lose citizenship, go to jail, can't inherit, stuff like that." And a good drill instructor can (most of the time) break down a hard case and make them part of the team. I'm not saying it would work on you, of course. And of course, service or no, if someone is the kind of person who would hold a grudge against innocent people just because, they'd probably treat them bad anyway, and at that point other laws come into play. Hopefully its something they'd mature out of.

Comment: I guess the real question is, what kinds of things would inspire you to want to help people in general and society as a whole?